# Differentiability Of $\frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Find if 
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)\\
> 0 & (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   is differentiable

So what I am using is the facts:

1. If the partial derivatives are continuous, then it is differentiable.
2. Differentiability by definition

Starting with checking that the function is continuous at $(0,0)$

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|+\left|\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}|x|+|y^2|=0
$$

The partial derivatives at $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ are:

$$
f_x=\frac{3x^2(x^2+y^2)-2x(x^3+y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{x^4+3x^2y^2-2xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$

and

$$
f_y=\frac{4y^3(x^2+y^2)-2y(x^3+y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{4x^2y^3+2y^5-2x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$

The partial derivatives at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ are:

$$
f_x(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\frac{(\Delta x)^3}{(\Delta x)^2}}{\Delta x}=1
$$

$$
f_y(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta y\to 0}\frac{\frac{(\Delta y)^4}{(\Delta y)^2}}{\Delta y}=\lim_{\Delta y\to 0} \Delta y=0
$$

It seems like that the partial derivatives are not continuous (so it will be easier to prove by definition):

$$
\lim_{(\Delta x, \Delta y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{(\Delta x)^3+(\Delta y)^4}{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}-\Delta x}{\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}}
$$

Using polar coordinates:

$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\frac{r^3\cos^3 \theta+r^4\sin^4 \theta}{r^2}-r\cos \theta}{r}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{{r\cos^3 \theta+r^2\sin^4 \theta}-r\cos \theta}{r}=\\=\lim_{r\to 0} \cos^3\theta +r\sin^4 \theta -\cos \theta
$$

Which does not exists as it depends on $\theta$ too so it is not differentiable

Is the way is valid?

Answer (score 3):

Its way too complicated. The easiest is to find the directional 
derivative
$$df_x(v)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}$$

In your case if $v=(a,b)$ you get

$$\frac{f(t(a,b))-f(0)}{t}=\frac{a^3+tb^4}{a^2+b^2}$$

So $$df_0(a,b)=\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$$

And this is NOT linear, thus the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: took me a while, I found a continuous (rational) function with all directional derivatives at the origin equal to zero, but still not Frechet differentiable  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390373/difference-between-g%c3%a2teaux-and-fr%c3%aachet-derivatives

Comment: Thanks! I see that it is complicated :) but is it correct?

Comment: Why do $\frac{f(t(a,b))-f(0)}{t}=\frac{a^3+tb^4}{a^2+b^2}$?