# Find If $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ Differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find if the function differentiable  $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
0, (x,y)=(0,0)\\
\end{cases}$$

Looking at

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta x}{|\Delta x|}$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta y\to 0}\frac{-\Delta y}{|\Delta y|}$

Which both has no limit and therefore no partial derivative, if just one partial derivative was not defined, is it enough to say that the function is not differentiable

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but if you approach $(0,0)$ from the lines $y=2x$ and $y=3x$, the derivative at $0$ yields different values

Comment: @imranfat You mean that it is not continuous too?

Comment: I did not say that the function is not continuous. But if you do the substitutions I suggested, what do you get then?

Comment: On a more general note, If both partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist near $(0,0)$ and are both continuous at Origin, then $f$ is differentiable. So I am sure you calculate both partial derivatives, right? Continuity?

Comment: @imranfat Sorry, I did not understand, if $f_x$ or $f_y$ do not exist, so $f$ is not differentiable? am I correct?

Comment: That is right. Also, please check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685572/differentiability-of-fracx3y4x2y2?rq=1